# Performance of website with multiple files

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing a website where you can order a product. This product has a lot of options etc so the user has to go through 10 steps to complete his/her order.

At the moment i have 1 file (index.php) which handles all steps. The code is a mess and the file is getting pretty big. I thought maybe splitting everything up in seperate files would be better. However, i don't want the user to reload the page at every step.

My first thoughts were PHP's `file_get_contents()` or using Ajax to load every file. But i don't know what method achieves the best performance? Or maybe you have an alternative?

Comment: Ordering in 10 steps? I would be long gone by then.

Comment: If you want it all on one page and handle page changes through javascript then I'd recommend using include files so you can have a main page, and then include the individual pages from individual files, which sounds like what I think you're going for yourself.

Comment: @putvande I work in the ecommerce industry (mainly) and would generally agree with you, but it depends on the products.  If it really needs that many steps then you can guarantee that the buyers are used to it.

Comment: Use functions, where each function does a different step. Or learn about MVC.

Comment: @putvande I would be too. Legal reasons..

Comment: @Archer What does that do with performance? Does it matter what size the individual files are if i use includes? (You mean PHP's `include()` method right?)

Comment: @RobinvdA Unless the page is ridiculous in size then I really wouldn't be concerned about sending it all in one hit.  It will make page changes instantaneous later.  Only your testing can really show whether it's best to get it all in one hit or to use ajax requests to get subsequent pages.  And yes, I meant php's include (or anything similar you wanted to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

keep 1 file, make a class and each step is a method of said class, you then invoke the right method upon reloading it via ajax. if you create several files it will be even messier.

Comment: My problem is mainly with the readability of my HTML. Right now i hide/display divs using jquery. Is that somewhat the same as you are suggesting?

Comment: I understand your pain, if I were you I'd create a blank page, meaning zero forms or at best only the step #1. after that, when the user submits step #1 I would remove step #1 and populate via ajax step #2 and so on until step #10. this way is much easier to handle the process. you could also save the partial status on your db in order to allow the user to go back to each step.

Comment: Thanks, i think i'm gonna go with your solution. Just a quick question, does this affect SEO?

Comment: about SEO, why would you want Google to index a form? if you were to create a bunch of pages that would be bad for various reasons (duplicated content, thin content etc) this way you should be all right though, cheers

Answer (score 1):

If the pages are just a bunch of forms/options, you could use jQuery/JavaScript to AJAX them in. And each time the user advances to another step, you could save the data into a cookie. Then at the end of all of the steps, submit all of the data at a single time to PHP. That would make your PHP code less scattered and would offload most of the processing work, for the individual steps, to the client's browser, which would reduce the server load caused by PHP processing each individual step (for all users buying your product).

You could store each form's HTML in separate HTML files on the server, or you could echo the HTML for a given step, from your PHP script based on a `$_GET['step']` value, etc.

Instead of hiding/displaying your divs with jQuery, this method would actually *replace* the HTML for a given step with the [next/previous step's HTML](https://api.jquery.com/load/).

Using PHP's `include` function is not going to improve performance because it acts the same as if the code of the included file was in place of the include directive, however it requires PHP to have some additional overhead because it has to [load and evaluate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the specified file.